# Setting up custom resolution on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a special display (from a Chinese seller on eBay) with following resolution: *1280x320*

On a Windows 10 machine (*with Nvidia Geforce 1080*) and after playing around with all the Nvidia Setting, I managed to get it to work properly at *1280x320*.

Now I would like to use in with another machine, running Ubuntu *16.04 LTS* (with an older Nvidia card using the open source nouveau drivers).

The correct resolution will of-course not show up by default. It chooses another *1280x720* resolution and that does not look good so in order to fix this, I do:

```
cvt to create 1280 320 output XXX
xrandr --newmode XXX
xrandr --addmode DVI-D-1 XXX
xrandr --output DVI-D-1 XXX
```

But doing this, `xrandr` does not complain or anything. but it results in a black screen on the monitor. It just says "No Signal" on the monitor. I tried a couple of other "refresh rate" and also `-r` (reduced) command when using cvt but none of them worked.

What else can be customized in Ubuntu when it comes to monitors?
On Widows (using the Nvidia tool) you can configure a ton of stuff such as "Color Depth", "Scan Type", "Total Pixels Horizontal and Vertical". Where can such options be changed on the Ubuntu side? I suppose that other than the resolution/refresh rate I am still not sending the exact right signal for the display.

Comment: Would you include the acctual output generated by `cvt 1280 320` and `gtf 1280 320` and `grep Modeline /var/log/Xorg.0.log`?